# How to make an Excel formula which totals several adjacent rows based on cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet with three columns: date, person and percentage. I would like to put in a data validation that flags cells if the total for a given data/person combination do not equal 100%. Is that possible?

In other words, in the custom formula of a data validation, I would like to make the following type of formula.

```
 =if(sum( cells with a (date = the date on this row, person = person on this row))=1)
```

Is there a function which will return the cells in a range conditioned on certain values, or will sum the cells.

Note that if it is not possible to do two cells, I have no issue adding a cell which combines both values for the purpose of affecting the lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `SUMIF` (for a single criteria), the [Microsoft SUMIF page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052092921033.aspx) on it, is pretty good. as is the [OfficeArticle's SUMIF](http://www.officearticles.com/excel/sumif_using_multiple_criteria_in_microsoft_excel.htm).

Or just `SUM` with an array function (see above article from officearticles) for multiple criteria. For instance in the sheet below I entered the formula without curly braces into G2, and helt Ctrl+Shift+Enter, then I drug the formula down.

[image: an excel array formula]

If you have many many rows, then you'll need to move on to using [DSUM](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052090691033.aspx) for speed reasons. As you noted in your comment, they have to have their own little faux-table somewhere.

Really it sounds like you're quickly moving past what Excel can do without busting into VBA. A database, or targeted application may be in your near future.

**edit:** added information on array formula, pretty picture

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm not seeing how to do it. Even with DSUM, the criteria seem geared to a hard coded value. I want the criteria to be the column name on top and the value in my current row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I know that your question has already been answered, but I thought I might bring your attention to the SUMPRODUCT() function. It's like SUMIF, but I personally find it easier to work with and easier to use AND or OR nested within

```
=Sumproduct((Range=Cell)*((Randge=ThisCell)+(Range=ThatCell))*(The figures to add up))
```

Hope this helps.

Mike